# Install FFmpeg package for Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg, laravel-8

I need to install the FFmpeg package for compress video server-side in Laravel, but I get an error when I try to install this package via composer. I read their documentation, but I don't know how I resolve this. So please help me to solve this issue.

**Error**

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg ^8.0 -> satisfiable by pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg[8.0.0].
> - pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg 8.0.0 requires illuminate/contracts ^9.0 -> found illuminate/contracts[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
>
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version
> constraint, e.g. "composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg:*" to figure
> out if any version is installable, or "composer require
> pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg:^2.1" if you know which you need.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check v8 [release note](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-ffmpeg/releases):

> As Laravel 9 has migrated from Flysystem 1.x to 3.x, this version is not compatible with Laravel 8 or earlier.

You can use `v7.8.1` :

```
composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg "7.8.1"
```

Comment: Yes, It's installed, Is there any commend to check the installed version.